# how to save matlab neural networks toolbox generated figures

Tags: matlab, neural-network, matlab-figure

In the matlab workspace the output/results can be easily saved. But when I train the network with some data to see the performance of the training (In Neural Network Toolbox), the regression plots along with the histograms and performance plots can not be saved as a figure file.currently i am using snipping tools to capture them.

My Question is how to do that? Is there any options to save those plots(generated in Maltab Neural Network toolbox)?

I would be grateful to have any codes/ answers regarding my inquiry. Many thanks.

I am adding to snapshot of plots which i want to save by commanding codes in matlab.

[image]

[image]

currently i am using snipping tools but when i put then in word, their property/image quality shrinks.

Comment: The quality of images that you have posted here seems fine. That they look worse in word is a completely different issue.

Comment: thanks for your comments. I also know that the issue is different but i want to capture the original figure file, thats why i need to save them as matlab figures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to identify the gfx object you want to snap-shoot (its handle). This may come from identifiable properties. Then you'd want to use `print` to save it to a file; you need to provide the file name, eventually the type; see the [help](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/print.html) for more details.

For example, if you want to save the figure with the tag 'my.awesome.fig', you may try:

```
h = findobj('Type', 'figure', 'tag', 'my.awesome.fig');
for k = 1:numel(h)
        print(h(k), sprintf('Pic%d.ps',k));
end;
```

Comment: thanks a lot. 

i tried with the above mentioned way, but it doesn't solve my need. The matlab Neural Network toolbox has inbuilt plotting options. When the net is trained with the data, i can click the plots( performance, Training state, Error histogram, Regression) and the figure generates automatically according to the way how it has been trained. Now the new figure which pops up can not be save with the type of codes that you mentioned.

Comment: Hmm... that is peculiar, indeed. But, just to be clear, the above code is just as an example. If, indeed, the window you want to print is a Matlab `figure`, it should be in the list of handles returned by `h = findobj('Type', 'figure')` or, if it's not, I'm afraid there's not much Matlab can do about capturing content. If it is among the figures, then its handle should be in `h`. Now, this might require some detective work, but you should find the specific property that makes it unique among the other figures using `get(h(1))`, `get(h(2))` etc. After you can adapt the code above to your needs.

Comment: @ CST-Link: Thanks, for your answers. This also does not work. I am wondering this toolbox generated plots may not be matlab figures. These are pure java figure (answers from another question by Amro). This has to be convert to a matlab figure and then capture it.

Comment: @ Amro: Could you please read this question and write codes for capturing the Matlab Neural Network Training (nntraintool) toolbox generated plots. I would be grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

The training figures other than nntraintool itself are genuine matlab figures. The tags are for example TRAINING_PLOTERRHIST TRAINING_PLOTPERFORM TRAINING_PLOTRESPONSE . the nntraintool figure is java--you can access it with nnjava.tools('nntraintool'). See Undocumented Matlab for how to manipulate java figures in Matlab.

```
Richard
```

Answer (score -1):

If you mention about the quality of figures only, you can do it by clicking EDIT/COPY in the figure menu.