# Matlab neural network toolbox save regression plot to file

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm trying to run a matlab script (generated by nftool, as my matlab knowledge is poor at best) with a rather large data set through my ssh connection on my school's multi-core compute server. Since I can't directly look at the graphical interface that's produce while training an the network, I'd like to save the plots to a file (the one I think I want the most is the regression plot) so I can look at it after the job runs. I've only edited the code to automatically import the data files

```
% Solve an Input-Output Fitting problem with a Neural Network
% Script generated by NFTOOL
% Created Tue Nov 11 21:20:40 CST 2014
%
% This script assumes these variables are defined:
%
%   NNinput - input data.
%   NNoutput - target data.

% sets the same seed every time, so the rand() sequence is always identical
RandStream.setGlobalStream(RandStream('mt19937ar','seed',1));

close all % closes all of the figures that you have generated in your program
clear all % deletes all stored variables in your workspace
clc       % removes all lines in your command window

NNinput = load('NNinput');
NNoutput = load('NNoutput');

inputs = NNinput;
targets = NNoutput;

inputs = inputs.';
targets = targets.';

% Create a Fitting Network
hiddenLayerSize = 10;
net = fitnet(hiddenLayerSize);

% Choose Input and Output Pre/Post-Processing Functions
% For a list of all processing functions type: help nnprocess
net.inputs{1}.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};
net.outputs{2}.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};

% Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
% For a list of all data division functions type: help nndivide
net.divideFcn = 'dividerand';  % Divide data randomly
net.divideMode = 'sample';  % Divide up every sample
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

% For help on training function 'trainlm' type: help trainlm
% For a list of all training functions type: help nntrain
net.trainFcn = 'trainlm';  % Levenberg-Marquardt

% Choose a Performance Function
% For a list of all performance functions type: help nnperformance
net.performFcn = 'mse';  % Mean squared error

% Choose Plot Functions
% For a list of all plot functions type: help nnplot
net.plotFcns = {'plotperform','plottrainstate','ploterrhist', ...
  'plotregression', 'plotfit'};


% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);

% Test the Network
outputs = net(inputs);
errors = gsubtract(targets,outputs);
performance = perform(net,targets,outputs)

% Recalculate Training, Validation and Test Performance
trainTargets = targets .* tr.trainMask{1};
valTargets = targets  .* tr.valMask{1};
testTargets = targets  .* tr.testMask{1};
trainPerformance = perform(net,trainTargets,outputs)
valPerformance = perform(net,valTargets,outputs)
testPerformance = perform(net,testTargets,outputs)
```

So far, all I've been able to come up with is...

```
h = findobj('Type', plotregression(targets, outputs), TRAINING_PLOTREGRESSION, 'regressionPlot');
for k = 1:numel(h)
    print(h(k), sprintf('Pic%d.ps',k));
end;
```

from this post [how to save matlab neural networks toolbox generated figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058891/how-to-save-matlab-neural-networks-toolbox-generated-figures)

and I'm guessing that I would add this to the end of the file, but I'm pretty sure that that isn't right. If anybody can help me out it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely the most **basic way** to save the plots about your training. You have chosen your plot functions in this part of your code:

```
% Choose Plot Functions
% For a list of all plot functions type: help nnplot
net.plotFcns = {'plotperform','plottrainstate','ploterrhist', ...
  'plotregression', 'plotfit'};
```

So now you can simply call each plot function at the end of your code (or anywhere after training the network) and save the plot with `print`:

```
plotperform(tr);
print('-dpsc', 'perform')
plottrainstate(tr);
print('-dpsc', 'trainstate')
ploterrhist(tr);
print('-dpsc', 'errhist')
plotregression(tr);
print('-dpsc', 'regression')
plotfit(tr);
print('-dpsc', 'fit')
```

The first argument of `print` selects the printer driver, in this case PostScript Level 3 color, and the second is the name of the figure. See [here](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html) for more information about `print`.